# Decentralized Chat feature in C#/WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

What are some options for implementing a chat feature in a C#/WPF desktop application? Is it possible to do this without a central server?

I have a desktop app and 1 user may be logged in at one time or 50 users may be logged in. I would like to add a chat feature that will allow them to talk to each other without relying on a central server. If I do have to use a central server, I assume that WCF would be the best option? Are there any solid examples of this with WCF?

Comment: I don't understand your question. How many users can be logged in at one time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can try using p2p binding from wcf take a look at [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WPFWCF_Chat_App_via_P2P.aspx).